# Avoid using a dll after a period of time

Tags: dll

I wrote the code inside a dll file that I do not want to be able to use after a while.

With the search I did, the only definite solution is to get time from the internet, but this dll file should be usable without the internet.
If there is a solution, please share

Comment: Use the computer time.

Comment: System time can be change by user

Comment: Yes, but doing so will cause problems for the user such as false dates on files.

Comment: Essentially you're trying to create the same concept as video game copy protection, look how that turned out. People will find a way around it. I think you should ask yourself the question: how much work is it worth?

Comment: So essentially you want to get real time clock on an arbitrary computer without the Internet connection? If that was possible, we wouldn't be using Internet time in the first place.